# Extract Text from Unstructured HTML using Python and Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup, python-requests

For the HTML code below, how do I extract the content below **aaa, bbb** after the 
 tag using regular Expressions and Beautiful Soup with the Python Requests Library

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <table style="max-width: 600px; margin: auto;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Swan</td>
                <td>Flower</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="background: #ffffff;">
                    <h5>Playground</h5>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <strong>Animal:</strong>
                    <br>aaa</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <strong>Fish:</strong>
                    <br>bbb</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
                    <form method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" name="yyy" value="7777">
                        <input type="hidden" name="rrr" value="wssss">
                        <input type="submit" value="djd ddd" style="width: 250px;">
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

I tried the code below but it doesn't seem to work

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

params = {
'api_key': 'APIKEY', 
'custom_cookies': 'PHPSESSID=SESSIONID,domain=DOMAIN.com;',}

response = requests.get(
url='www.example.com',
params=params,
timeout=120,
)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all('td', {'colspan': '2', 'strong': True})

#Extract the text content from each matching element
for result in results:
    br_tag = result.find('br')
    if br_tag:
        text_content = br_tag.next_sibling.strip()
        print(text_content)
```

**Expected Output**

aaa
bbb

**The Output I'm Getting**

[]

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_text = """\
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <table style="max-width: 600px; margin: auto;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Swan</td>
                <td>Flower</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="background: #ffffff;">
                    <h5>Playground</h5>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <strong>Animal:</strong>
                    <br>aaa</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <strong>Fish:</strong>
                    <br>bbb</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
                    <form method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" name="yyy" value="7777">
                        <input type="hidden" name="rrr" value="wssss">
                        <input type="submit" value="djd ddd" style="width: 250px;">
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")

for td in soup.select("td:has(strong)"):
    text = list(td.stripped_strings)[-1]
    print(text)
```

Prints:

```
aaa
bbb
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your .find_all('td') search attributes are too specific. You're asking for  tags that include an attribute called 'strong', not tags that contain a 'strong' tag.

Once you have your list of td objects, there are several ways to filter.

Here's an example (I saved your html example as a file locally, so no need for requests, but it will work the same way once you have your soup).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with open('to_parse.html') as response:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response)

attrs = {
    'colspan':'2',
    # 'strong':True, # <- remove this
}

results = soup.find_all('td', attrs=attrs)
# Using the fact that your desired content is the last item in the <td> tag. 
# If that is not always true, you will need a different approach to filtering 
# the td contents.
text_content = [result.contents[-1] for result in results if result.find('br')]
print(*text_content)

>>> aaa bbb
```